# Java to Objective c

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, porting

My problem:

I have code in Java that I need to port to Objective-C where

```
Obj[i] is byte[],  
Buffer is byte[],   
index is int
```

In my Objective C I have declared

```
Obj[i] is char**    
Buffer is char*  
index is int
```

and I am  not able to convert this line `buffer[index] = ((Byte)obj[i]).byteValue();`

```
case cw_BYTE_obj:

if(obj[i] == NULL)
{

    buffer[index] = 0x01;
    index++;
    buffer[index] = ((Byte)obj[i]).byteValue();
    index++;
}
```

**orginal java code**

```
case cw_BYTE_obj: 
if(obj[i] == null){
buffer[index] = 0x00;
index++;
}else{
buffer[index] = 0x01;
index++;
buffer[index] = ((Byte)obj[i]).byteValue();
index++;
}
break;
```

`

Comment: Please clarify, post the original java code and your ported objective C code. If obj is byte[] why don't just assign `buffer[index] = obj[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why is obj a char** in obj-c when it's a byte[] in java?
Anyhow, so you want a char to go into buffer[index], and obj[i] is char** so is probably a pointer to a char* ??  Depending on what you're putting into obj, you will probably be after something like buffer[index] = *(obj[i]);

Comment: if it is only (char *) i cant put obj[i]==Null so i declare char **

Comment: how to port these code `return data.length != 0?new Byte(data[0]) : null;` i am doing this way this not showing proper result `return datalen!= 0?malloc(sizeof(char) *data[0])  :NULL;` it is rite **java `data` is `byte` **In obj C** datalen `int datalen = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data);`

Comment: I think you would be better off using the cocoa classes for what you are trying to do.  Using an NSValue over a char would allow it to be nil, or NSData/NSMutableData will allow you to have an array of chars that can be nil.